# how to detect events that are not well ordered with respect to dates

Tags: r

Here is a representation of my dataset:

```
set.seed(1)

Date<-c(1:6,1:8,1:10)
ID<-c(rep(1,3*2),rep(2,4*2),rep(3,5*2))
Surgery<-c(c("Surg1",NA,NA,NA,"Surg2",NA),
        c(NA,NA,NA,"Surg.a",NA,NA,"Surg.f",NA),
        c("Surg.C",NA,NA,"Surg.A",NA,NA,"Surg.X",NA,NA,NA))
NumberOfSurgery<-c(rep(2,6),rep(2,8),rep(3,10))
OrderOfSurgery<-c(1,rep(NA,3),2,rep(NA,4),2,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,3,NA,NA,2,rep(NA,3))

mydata<-data.frame(ID,Date,Surgery,NumberOfSurgery,OrderOfSurgery)
mydata
```

I have these three individuals who have all had a series of surgeries and are being followed up. The data is already sorted by date. And the different surgeries are also ordered (chronologically) for each patient from the variable (`OrderOfSurgery`).
On the other hand, we can see that there is a mismatch of dates order and surgeries order for the patients 2(`OrderOfSurgery = 2` before `OrderOfSurgery=1`) and the patients 3(`OrderOfSurgery = 3` before `OrderOfSurgery= 2`). I would like to extract all the individuals for whom there is no consistency between the order of the dates and the order of the surgeries. Knowing that in my real database there are at less more than 400 thousand individuals and more than 2 million observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to replace `NA` value in `OrderOfSurgery` to the last known value and select such individuals who has at least one such mismatch in their data.

Mismatch is considered when the current value of surgery is less than the previous value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata %>%
  mutate(new_order = OrderOfSurgery) %>%
  fill(new_order) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(new_order < lag(new_order, default = 0))) %>%
  select(-new_order) %>%
  ungroup

#      ID  Date Surgery NumberOfSurgery OrderOfSurgery
#   <dbl> <int> <chr>             <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1     2     1 NA                    2             NA
# 2     2     2 NA                    2             NA
# 3     2     3 NA                    2             NA
# 4     2     4 Surg.a                2              2
# 5     2     5 NA                    2             NA
# 6     2     6 NA                    2             NA
# 7     2     7 Surg.f                2              1
# 8     2     8 NA                    2             NA
# 9     3     1 Surg.C                3              1
#10     3     2 NA                    3             NA
#11     3     3 NA                    3             NA
#12     3     4 Surg.A                3              3
#13     3     5 NA                    3             NA
#14     3     6 NA                    3             NA
#15     3     7 Surg.X                3              2
#16     3     8 NA                    3             NA
#17     3     9 NA                    3             NA
#18     3    10 NA                    3             NA
```